# Using Get-Childitem at root of UNC Path \\SERVERNAME

Tags: powershell, get-childitem, network-shares

We're trying to use PowerShell as a file-replication tool, but having an issue.

The source server is a Linux-based closed OS, where users, through a GUI, create multiple network shares, which are then accessible by the UNC path `\\SERVERNAME\NETWORKSHARE`. In the OS, of course, the NETWORKSHARE is actually located multiple levels deeper than the root.

We've talked to the developer of the OS, and they cannot/will not enable access to the root of the folder where all the NETWORKSHARE folders are stored.

I've turned to PowerShell to try and find a way. My initial thinking was to send a `Get-ChildItem -Directory` to `\\SERVERNAME` to grab all the NETWORKSHARES, and then pipe that to `Copy-Item/Robocopy`, but it doesn't work.

I know the server needs their own local (non-AD) credentials.

Is there a way to do what I want to do that I'm just not seeing ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `net view` command with an IP will enumerate accessible SMB/Samba shares.
This PowerShell script parses the output and returns a `[PSCustomObject]` with Server and Share properties.

```
## Enum-SambaShares.ps1
$ServerList = ('192.168.133.67','192.168.133.46','192.168.133.76','192.168.133.28')
$ServerShares = ForEach ($Server in $ServerList) {
    net view "\\$Server" 2>$Null | Select-String '^([^ ]+)\s+(Disk|Platte)' | 
        ForEach-Object {
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                Server = $Server
                Share  = $_.matches.groups[1].Value
            }
        }
}
$ServerShares
```

Sample output:

```
Server        Share
------        -----
192.168.133.67 Backup
192.168.133.67 Daten
192.168.133.67 Video-Unc
192.168.133.46 SambaShare
192.168.133.46 UserName
192.168.133.76 C
192.168.133.28 McDaten
192.168.133.28 Music
192.168.133.28 UserName
```

Comment: Yes! This is almost exactly what I need. The results are perfect, but the ONE thing that is missing, is that I need this script to access the remote server as a local user on the remote server, how would I go about doing this ?

Comment: Well you can authenticate against a server with `net use` but that needs a share `net use \\server\share /user:test testpassword`

Comment: Yeah I know about that, hence my question. I need to use remote server credentials to even access the root if the server.

Comment: Welp, never mind that question. Not able to pass credentials to Net View, BUT, I was able to manually add the credentials to Credential Manager, and it all seems to work now. Will just have to do a final try on another VM later on. Thank you for this help, it will save us SOOOOO much time and during our server backup!

Answer (score 0):

Parsing the output of `new view` is a bit clumsy. Here's an approach that calls the `NetShareEnum` Win32 API directly from PowerShell and outputs the results as an object:

```
# Get-NetShare.ps1

#requires -version 2

param(
  [String] $ComputerName = "."
)

Add-Type @"
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct SHARE_INFO_1
{
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
  public string shi1_netname;
  public uint shi1_type;
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
  public string shi1_remark;
}
public static class NetApi32
{
  [DllImport("netapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
  public static extern int NetApiBufferFree(IntPtr Buffer);
  [DllImport("netapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
  public static extern int NetShareEnum(
    StringBuilder servername,
    int level,
    ref IntPtr bufptr,
    uint prefmaxlen,
    ref int entriesread,
    ref int totalentries,
    ref int resume_handle);
}
"@

$pBuffer = [IntPtr]::Zero
$entriesRead = $totalEntries = $resumeHandle = 0
$result = [NetApi32]::NetShareEnum(
  $ComputerName,        # servername
  1,                    # level
  [Ref] $pBuffer,       # bufptr
  [UInt32]::MaxValue,   # prefmaxlen
  [Ref] $entriesRead,   # entriesread
  [Ref] $totalEntries,  # totalentries
  [Ref] $resumeHandle   # resumehandle
)
if ( ($result -eq 0) -and ($pBuffer -ne [IntPtr]::Zero) -and ($entriesRead -eq $totalEntries) ) {
  $offset = $pBuffer.ToInt64()
  for ( $i = 0; $i -lt $totalEntries; $i++ ) {
    $pEntry = New-Object IntPtr($offset)
    $shareInfo = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStructure($pEntry, [Type] [SHARE_INFO_1])
    $shareInfo
    $offset += [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SizeOf($shareInfo)
  }
  [Void] [NetApi32]::NetApiBufferFree($pBuffer)
}
if ( $result -ne 0 ) {
  Write-Error -Exception (New-Object ComponentModel.Win32Exception($result))
}
```

You can get disk shares of a remote computer thus:

```
Get-NetShare sambaservername | Where-Object { $_.shi1_type -eq 0 }
```

Comment: This would be perfect, but the source-OS is Linux-based, not Windows-based, so there's no WMI to answer on the other end :P

Comment: @AlexPilon - see my updated PowerShell answer that calls the Windows API directly (without parsing the output of `net view`).